# Controller - Where to connect views and models in Backbone?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, backbone.js

- My first approach was to have each View initialize (`new`) its own Model, but as the project grows it is getting difficult to maintain as more views get added.
- Another way could be to have the App level View do the job.

Since Backbone does not provide a Controller class. What is the best practice to connect views and models in a medium size project in Backbone?

*I know this is yet another Backbone Controller question from a MVC newbie! And that Backbone is not strict MVC. I only found some answers to this question in SO that were outdated and mixed Router and Controller concepts.*

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difficulties mentioned in your first bullet?

Comment: This is due mostly to some views (and models) being nested, it is increasingly difficult to keep track of which view initializes which model. Quickly it becomes a dependency nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just connect them when you create your view by specifying the model in the configuration object you pass to the view constructor:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var myModel = new MyModel();
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend();
var myView = new MyView({model: myModel});
```

Comment: In which part of the application is this best done? In the root of the application? `$(function(){/*  */})`... page load?

Comment: it depends of how you decide to structure your application. If you use AMD approach which I strongly suggest you should consider to use modular backbone bootstrap https://github.com/suprememoocow/modular-backbone-bootstrap